# Should I feel bad answering questions when others have posted partial solutions?

Tags: discussion, answers

I often see questions with 2-3 answers all having good information but none that consolidates that info. Also sometimes the right answer is in a comment. I always tell those guys to post it as an answer. And to the others I comment there answer and tell then to add the rest.

But very often these peoples do not react. So am I bad posting an answer that's already there on the page, just not in an organised fashion? I know it's quite in the spirit of stackoverflow but still feel bad.

Comment: If it needs any clarification, my upvote means that you should NOT feel bad. That is, I condone your methodology. I disagree with the sentiment that what you're doing is "bad". StackOverflow isn't perfect, that much is obvious. So let's all do something about it. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60810/on-incorporating-other-peoples-answer-to-make-your-own-answer-awesomer

Comment: My upvote means the same. The most complete answer is the answer that deserves the upvotes, and should get accepted.

Comment: And if you really feel bad, start your answer with "As so and so already stated in another answer..."

Answer (score 4):

*(With a pseudo like yours, why are you worrying about being bad? :)*

Seriously, no. You shouldn't feel bad.

There is a sort of tension between the 'fair-play' of wanting to respect other people's rep and the 'big picture' of questions and answers belonging to the whole community.

You are completely right to consolidate/improve the answers, and in this case, if the other users aren't reacting, I don't even see any reason why you would even think of feeling bad.

Comment: I am not worried about anything exept overthrow the Caliph and take his place :-)